# SSH to Pivotal cloud foundary

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I am trying to SSH to Pivotal Cloud Foundary, after i logged in, i got the following error:

```
C:\Users\user>cf allow-space-ssh Dev
Enabling ssh support for space 'Dev'...

FAILED
Error enabling ssh support for space Dev: Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action
```

What is the best way to SSH or what could be happening here?

Comment: the answer is in your repsonse code, "403, You are not authorized to perform the requested action"  you need to get authorization, and since its SSH you probably need to get a key pair

Comment: Your statement is "I am trying to SSH to PCF", yet you are using `cf allow-space-ssh Dev`. I think you are confused on which commands to use. 
Platform operators only can enable ssh. Once they have you can ONLY ssh into an app instance's container by `cf ssh <appnm>`.

Comment: Assuming you have successfully done `cf login`, and the platform operator has enabled ssh, you can ssh into the container using `cf ssh <appnm>`. You do not need any key pair.

Answer (score 1):

`cf allow-space-ssh` command can be executed only by `Space Managers` and not by `Space Developers`

Space Developers can only enable `SSH` at App-Level. I suggest you to read [this Link](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html)